# Passing an array from one view controller to the another view controller

Tags: arrays, cocoa-touch, view, controller

I have read all of the posts about passing data from one view controller to another but I am still at a loss as to how that is done.  Simply put, I have an array that is built in my MainViewController and need to use that array in my DisplayViewController.

I am simply doing the following

```
//DisplayViewController
self.items = mainViewController.items
```

I would think that this notation would work but I keep getting the following error:
Request for member 'mainViewController' in something not a structure or union.

Since I am a real newbie I cannot really understand some of the answers that I read.  So if someone can put it in laymans terms, I would really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's done the other way around. Just before you push your DisplayViewController on the stack (or however you make it visible), you set its `items` property.

```
detailViewController.items = self.items;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: THanks!  I am not sure if I am doing this properly.  Using the view Controller names that are in my program, does this equate to what you were trying to convey:

    //MainViewController
    MainViewController.line = self.lines
    [self presentModalViewController: self.DisplayViewController              animated:NO];

Comment: `displayViewController.line = [self.lines objectAtIndex:idx]; [self presentModalViewController:displayViewController animated:NO];`